# Should I use a DC-DC converter or an LDO?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, heat, ldo

In my project, I am designing a board which is supplied by a battery. The battery is a LiPo, 3.7 V, 1000 mAh, so its voltage range is 3 - 4.2 V.

All the components on the board need a fixed voltage of 3.3 V. In some configuration the board can draw 1 A, but most of the time it draws about 50 mA.

I need to convert the battery voltage to 3.3 V. I was thinking of 3 options:

- Option 1. Using a buck-boost converter
- Option 2. Using a buck converter and electronically cut the power supply when it is approaching 3.3 V (let's say 3.6 V)
- Option 3. Same as option 2 but with an LDO

**Do you see better options?**

My conclusions are as follows:

- Option 1 is the most expensive option, and price does matter.
- All the 3.3 V buck converters I have found only accepts input voltages starting at 4 V. **Is it a normal behavior that bucks need a voltage gap to work?**
- Option 3 seems to be the best option. But when the board draws 1 A, I would need to dissipate maximum (4.2 V - 3.3 V) * 1 A = 0.9 W, which is too much because the board is very small so it would badly dissipate heat, and heat does matter...

**Which options would you use in such a case? Do you have advice?**

Comment: If you need 3.3 V out with only 3.0 V in,  then buck-boost is the only one of your options that can possibly do the job.

Comment: You should also consider the efficiency required (that is -battery life?) and the fact that a switching regulator is producing a noisy output comparing to LDO, and needs certain design considerations to reduce the effects. Given all the points, you have all of the information to decide yourself.

Comment: How often does the board draw 1A?  For how long?  What are the discharge curves for your battery?  Most Lipos stay > 3.5V until they're almost fully discharged so a LDO might work.

Comment: It is okay if I do not use the battery all the way down to 3 V. Cutting it at 3.6 V is acceptable. It can draw 1 A 25 % of the time, sometimes during dozens of minutes. I do not have the discharge curve of the battery but I think most LiPo 3.7 V battery discharge curves are more or less the same, am I right?

Comment: 1Ah, 25% of the time @1A, cut @3.6V? How long does the battery need to power the circuit?

Comment: Include SEPIC in your options

Comment: Related/similar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/330922/2028

Comment: What is the load that draws 1A on 3V3? How accurate does it need its 3V3 to be? Does it use a buck converter to convert to a lower voltage to power a big cpu?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like LiPo batteries stay above 3.3V in normal charge levels, and drop to 3.0V when they're below ~80% capacity.

[image]

Image source: https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/voltages

Based on this, **you can stick with an LDO since it's the cheapest and easiest way to step down a voltage**, assuming you don't mind the efficiency losses when your battery is >4.0V. LDOs will dissipate any unused power as heat; the greater the difference between Vin and Vout, the lower the efficiency. A benefit when compared with switching topologies is a much smaller ripple on Vout, which is good for sensitive electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a boost converter chip in a SEPIC configuration. This can act as step up and step down in one circuit.